# cartopy: Why isn't my circle moving along the great circle path?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm having trouble using cartopy ...

I have some locations (mainly changing in lat) and I want to draw some circles along the this great circle path. Here's the code

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import cartopy
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

points = np.array([[-145.624, 14.8853],
[-145.636, 10.6289],
[-145.647, 6.3713]])

proj2      = ccrs.Orthographic(central_longitude= points[1,0], central_latitude=  points[1,1]) # Spherical map
pad_radius = compute_radius(proj2, points[1,0],points[1,1], 35)

resolution = '50m'

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(112,6), dpi=96)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=proj2)
ax.set_xlim([-pad_radius, pad_radius])
ax.set_ylim([-pad_radius, pad_radius])

ax.imshow(np.tile(np.array([[cfeature.COLORS['water'] * 255]], dtype=np.uint8), [2, 2, 1]), origin='upper', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), extent=[-180, 180, -180, 180])

ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', resolution, edgecolor='black', facecolor=cfeature.COLORS['land']))
ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('cultural', 'admin_0_countries', resolution, edgecolor='black', facecolor='none'))

# Loop over the points
# Compute the projected circle at that point
# Plot it!
for i in range(len(points)):
    thePt = points[i,0], points[i,1]
    r_or = compute_radius(proj2, points[i,0], points[i,1],  10)
    print(thePt, r_or)
    c= mpatches.Circle(xy=thePt, radius=r_or, color='red', alpha=0.3, transform=proj2, zorder=30)
    # print(c.contains_point(points[i,0], points[i,1]))
    ax.add_patch(c)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Compute radius is:

```
def compute_radius(ortho, lon, lat, radius_degrees):
    '''
    Compute a earth central angle around lat, lon
    Return phi in terms of projection desired
    This only seems to work for non-PlateCaree projections
    '''
    phi1 = lat + radius_degrees if lat <= 0 else lat - radius_degrees
    _, y1 = ortho.transform_point(lon, phi1, ccrs.PlateCarree()) # From lon/lat in PlateCaree to ortho
    return abs(y1)
```

And what I get for output:

> (-145.624, 14.8853) 638304.2929446043 (-145.636, 10.6289)
> 1107551.8669600221 (-145.647, 6.3713) 1570819.3871025692

You can see the interpolated points going down in lat (lon is almost constant), but the radius is growing smaller with lat and the location isn't changing at all???

[image]

Comment: You need to check what you plot. Once you create `Circle` patch, you can check if it contains the coordinates you use for its center. See 'contains_point' here https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html

Comment: This should be easy to formulate as an MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code incomplete, lacking input data, etc. 

Most likely however, you're plotting lon/lat coordinates as if they're `Orthographic`, either convert them or use the appropriate transform.

Comment: I can't get 'contains_point' to even work when it has the cartopy transform in it... ??? I've reworked the example to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `thePt` is in lat/lon with a PlateCarree projection. Your plot is in an orthographic projection. The `transform` in the call to create the `Circle` should be `ccrs.PlateCarree()`. `c= mpatches.Circle(xy=thePt, radius=r_or, color='red', alpha=0.3, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), zorder=30)`

Comment: I guess I don't understand what transform_point is doing. But yes, thePt is a lat/lon in geocentric (geodetic) coordinates. So by making the call with the PlateCarree transform I guess I'm just saying 'that' -- i.e. - thePt is lat/lon

Comment: I think I just need degs to meters via 
def deg2m(val_degree):
    """
    Compute surface distance in meters for a given angular value in degrees
    """
    geod84 = Geod(ellps='WGS84')
    lat0, lon0 = 0, 90
    _, _, dist_m = geod84.inv(lon0, lat0,  lon0+val_degree, lat0)
    return dist_m

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for rewriting the example, that clears things up!

I think the key point is that you need to convert the x/y coordinates that you use for the `Circle` as well, or vice versa keep the radius also in lat/lon (probably close but not identical). Now you mix and match, where the radius is based on the Orthographic projection, but the x/y are lat/lon. Because of that, the points do move along the path you want, but it's just incredibly close to the origin of the plot due to the incorrect units.

Something like this might help you along:

```py
points = np.array([
    [-145.624, 14.8853],
    [-145.636, 10.6289],
    [-145.647, 6.3713]],
)

proj2      = ccrs.Orthographic(
    central_longitude= points[1,0], 
    central_latitude=  points[1,1],
)
pad_radius = compute_radius(proj2, points[1,0],points[1,1], 35)

resolution = '50m'

fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    figsize=(12,6), dpi=96, subplot_kw=dict(projection=map_proj, facecolor=cfeature.COLORS['water']),
)

ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', resolution, edgecolor='black', facecolor=cfeature.COLORS['land']))
ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('cultural', 'admin_0_countries', resolution, edgecolor='black', facecolor='none'))

ax.set_extent((-pad_radius, pad_radius, -pad_radius, pad_radius), crs=proj2)

for lon, lat in points:
    r_or = compute_radius(proj2, lon, lat,  10)

    ### I think this is what you intended!
    mapx, mapy = proj2.transform_point(lon, lat, ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ###

    c= mpatches.Circle(xy=(mapx, mapy), radius=r_or, color='red', alpha=0.3, transform=proj2, zorder=30)
    ax.add_patch(c)
```

[image]

Comment: That's close! Thanks... I completely forgot about the transform... I was only thinking about the radius and forgo "transform_point" ... but the circle needs to be the same radius as it moves north?!!? Why is it changing?

Comment: I guess I don't understand what compute_radius() is doing then... I stole that from another post!

Comment: I think I can use a deg to meters conversion to get the radius correct...

Comment: I suggest you reformat your question, because this doesn't make much sense. You define the radius in degrees, why would you expect it to remain the same on a projection that has a highly non-linear relation to lat/lon?

Comment: That's not correct... The size of the projected circle should not change very much over the course of several degrees of lat as viewed in this projection. I was not using the computation for the size of the circle. It should be in meters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete answer. I was not converting the lat/lon into the orthographic projection coords... and apparently it wants the size of the circle to be in meters -- hence I use a function to change degrees (which I know for my circle) into meters:

```
def deg2m(val_degree):
    """
    Compute surface distance in meters for a given angular value in degrees
    Uses the definition of a degree on the equator... 
    """
    geod84 = Geod(ellps='WGS84')
    lat0, lon0 = 0, 90
    _, _, dist_m = geod84.inv(lon0, lat0,  lon0+val_degree, lat0)
    return dist_m


# Data points where I wish to draw circles
points = np.array([[-111.624, 30.0],
[-111.636, 35.0],
[-111.647, 40.0]])

proj2      = ccrs.Orthographic(central_longitude= points[1,0], central_latitude=  points[1,1]) # Spherical map
pad_radius = compute_radius(proj2, points[1,0],points[1,1], 45) # Generate a region bigger than our circles

resolution = '50m'

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(112,6), dpi=96)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=proj2)
# Bound our plot/map
ax.set_xlim([-pad_radius, pad_radius])
ax.set_ylim([-pad_radius, pad_radius])

ax.imshow(np.tile(np.array([[cfeature.COLORS['water'] * 255]], dtype=np.uint8), [2, 2, 1]), origin='upper', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), extent=[-180, 180, -180, 180])
ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', resolution, edgecolor='black', facecolor=cfeature.COLORS['land']))
ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('cultural', 'admin_0_countries', resolution, edgecolor='black', facecolor='none'))

r_or = deg2m(17) # Compute the size of circle with a radius of 17 deg

# Loop over the points
# Compute the projected circle at that point
# Plot it!
for i in range(len(points)):
    thePt = points[i,0], points[i,1]
    # Goes from lat/lon to coordinates in our Orthographic projection
    mapx, mapy = proj2.transform_point(points[i,0], points[i,1], ccrs.PlateCarree())
    c= mpatches.Circle(xy=(mapx, mapy), radius=r_or, color='red', alpha=0.3, transform=proj2, zorder=30)
    ax.add_patch(c)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

I've verified that the deg2m routine works since it's about 17 deg of lat from Phoenix AZ to the Canadian border (approx) which is nearby these test points.